# Вывод даных из массива через цикл динамических ключей

Tags: php, laravel

Привествую. Тема проблемы еще не понятней чем сама проблема :)

**Суть проблемы**
Данных приходят в .blade.php с таким ключами

```
"description_1" => "Описание"
"description_2" => "Описание"
"description_3" => "Описание"
"description_4" => "Описание"
```

могу конечно просто продублировать код и выводить описание

```
{{ $rules->description_1 }}
{{ $rules->description_2 }}
{{ $rules->description_3 }}
{{ $rules->description_4 }}
```

Но учитовая что мне надо их в некий html обернуть то возникла проблема как циклом организовать вывод ? где-то так я это вижу как должно быть (конечно это так не работает)

```
@for($i= 1; $i<5; $i++) 
   {{$rules->'description_'.$i}}
@endfor
```

Любой помощи буду рад :)

Comment: Попробуйте так: eval('$rules->description_'.%i.';');

Comment: @nightfla Правильное решение такое eval('return $rules->description_'.$i.';'). Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Решение

```
eval('return $rules->description_'.$i.';')
```

Спасибо **[nightflash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/385510/nightflash)**

Answer (score 0):

```
@for($i= 1; $i<5; $i++) 
    {{ object_get($rules, "description_{$i}") }}
@endfor
```